# Add Solidify Modifier to a plane with a different image on each side

Tags: materials, modifiers

I have a plane with an image on each side. The shader uses a Geometry node with Backfacing. I want to give the plane a little thickness and I tried that by using a Solidify Modifier which did give the plane thickness. The issue I have is then both sides of the plan use the same image and I need to have different images on each plane.

How it should look

[image: How the page should look]

With Modifier

[image: With solidifier Modifier]

Material Nodes

[image: Nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the solidify modifier, you are giving the object "faces" with their normals pointed outwards. This means that in the new "box" you create, all the "backfacing" faces are facing the inside (so you cant see them). You can either apply the modifier and add a different material for the different faces (as desired), or you could select the face you want to be different and flip the normals on it.